# Looking for a GUI application to enter linux commands

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, tcl, command-line-interface

I am looking for a GUI console where I can enter linux commands in an entry widget and the result will be output in a text area widget. Is there is such software available? Something like this:

[image]

A console programs like gnome-terminal or xterm, the screen keeps scrolling with every new command, and I find this annoying specially when the result has a few dozen lines.

I would like to visualize the command and the result at the same time, alike a browser entering a web address in the address bar and obtaining the website as a result.

Thank you.

Comment: You might have more luck over at http://unix.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow is usually for programming specific questions, this is more of a general Linux application question.

Comment: Why do you care what language such a tool is implemented in? Would you refuse to use a program just because it's written in Perl or C?

Comment: @abarnert, no of course don't mind what language is on, but it will be easier to look at the code, rather that a program written in C.

Comment: @PherricOxide, thanks for the advice. I already post it in there as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well, such a thing is easy to implement in Tcl.

```
package require Tk 8.5
grid [ttk::entry .input -textvariable input] -sticky nesw
grid [text .text] -sticky nesw
grid rowconfigure . .text -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . .text -weight 1
bind .input <Return> execute
bind .input <Up> {histwalk -1}
bind .input <Down> {histwalk 1}

proc execute {} {
    history add $::input
    set ::eventcnt 0
    .text delete 1.0 end
    catch {exec /bin/bash -c $::input} res
    .text insert 1.0 $res
    .input selection range 0 end
}

set eventcnt 0
proc histwalk i {
   incr ::eventcnt $i
   set ::input [history event $::eventcnt]
   .input selection range 0 end
}
```

Comment: Well, I omitted the scrollbar, but you hate scrolling anyway, right?

Comment: Thank you for the program, it works as expected but I am looking for something with more features, like command history. Is it possible to embed tclreadline in the ttk::entry widget to include all the readline features?

Comment: tclreadline would be the wrong tool for this, but maybe a little histroy stuff helps.

Comment: Add line `if {$::eventcnt == [history nextid]} {set ::eventcnt 1}` after `incr ::eventcnt $i`. Otherwise will throw an error.